# Regex to find multiple combinations from a string with specific characters as start and end

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, expression

I am trying to find matches of possible strings with start characters: 'ATG' and end characters 'TAA' or 'TGA' or 'TAG'. 
For example, if my string is:

```
seq = 'GATGATCGATGCTGACGTATAGGTTAAC'
```

I want to use regular expressions to match these 3:

```
match1 = 'ATGATCGATGCTGA'

match2 = 'ATGATCGATGCTGACGTATAG'

match3 = 'ATGATCGATGCTGACGTATAGGTTAA'
```

And the same if you use the second 'ATG':

```
MATCH4 = 'ATGCTGA'

MATCH5 = 'ATGCTGACGTATAG'

MATCH6 = 'ATGCTGACGTATAGGTTAA'
```

So far i have written this:

```
Frame1_ORF = re.match(\r '(^(ATG)?:(TGA|TAA|TAG)$)',Frame1)
```

But i have sth incorrect with my syntax or my symbols. 
Could you help me find these 6 matches?

Thanks.

Comment: There are some issues: 1) you did not form a correct string literal with the regex pattern,  2) `re.match` only searches for a match at the start of the string. Then comes the pattern.

Comment: Do you expect the string starts by `ATG` or a substring in a bigger string to start with `ATG`?

Comment: @Arount i expect the string to start by ATG.

Comment: Guys there was a mistake with the page. Stars shouldn't exist. I just wanted to make them bold to look easier to the eye but for some reason the page appeared them like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to extract strings as defined within a bigger string, this could do the job

```
matches = (
    '**ATG**ATCG**ATG**C**TGA**',
    '**ATG**ATCG**ATG**C**TGA**CGTA**TAG**',
    '**ATG**ATCG**ATG**C**TGA**CGTA**TAG**GT**TAA**'
)
for string in matches:
    print(re.findall('((ATG)(.*)(TGA|TAA|TAG))', string)[0][0])
```

Output

```
ATG**ATCG**ATG**C**TGA
ATG**ATCG**ATG**C**TGA**CGTA**TAG
ATG**ATCG**ATG**C**TGA**CGTA**TAG**GT**TAA
```

Comment: If i remove the stars from the seq, how would your code be? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To build on the answer provided by @Arount:

```
matches = (
    '**ATG**ATCG**ATG**C**TGA**',
    '**ATG**ATCG**ATG**C**TGA**CGTA**TAG**',
    '**ATG**ATCG**ATG**C**TGA**CGTA**TAG**GT**TAA**'
)
for string in matches:
    print(re.findall('(\*\*(?:ATG)(?:.*)(?:TGA|TAA|TAG)\*\*)', string)[0])
```

It outputs:

```
**ATG**ATCG**ATG**C**TGA**
**ATG**ATCG**ATG**C**TGA**CGTA**TAG**
**ATG**ATCG**ATG**C**TGA**CGTA**TAG**GT**TAA**
```

The 2 changes I made:

- Appended and prepended `\*\*`
- The inner groups are non-capturing ones now (`?:`). It's no longer needed to do `[0][0]`. Just `[0]` now.

Comment: If i remove the stars from the seq, how would your code be? Thanks.

Comment: About the same. But it may find more sequences.

Comment: Just remove `\*\*` at the end and beginning. I think it's pretty self explanatory

Comment: Cool.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
import re

resp =[]
seq = 'G**ATG**ATCG**ATG**C**TGA**CGTA**TAG**GT**TAA**C'


while re.findall(r'(?<=ATG)(.*)(?=(TGA|TAA|TAG))',seq):
    seq = re.findall(r'(?<=ATG)(.*)(?=(TGA|TAA|TAG))', seq)
    resp.append("ATG"+seq[0][0]+seq[0][1])
    seq="ATG"+seq[0][0]
print(resp)
```

Comment: If i remove the stars from the seq, how would your code be? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to generate a list of combinations of the sequence that follow the rules of the desired sequence, and filter the final result so that all the sequences left exist in the input sequence:

```
seq = 'G**ATG**ATCG**ATG**C**TGA**CGTA**TAG**GT**TAA**C'
def new_data(f):
  def wrapper():
    full = map('**'.join, f(seq.split('**')))
    return list(filter(lambda x:x in seq, full)))
  return wrapper

@new_data
def outer(data):
  def combinations(d, current = []):
    if current and current[0] == 'ATG' and current[-1] in ['TAA', 'TGA', 'TAG']:
      yield current
    else:
      for i in d:
        if i in ['TAA', 'TGA', 'TAG'] and current:
          yield current + [i]
        else:
          if not current and i == 'ATG':
             yield from combinations(d, [i]+current)
          elif current and current.count(i) < seq.split('**').count(i):
             yield from combinations(d, current+[i])
  return list(combinations(data))


results = list(map(lambda x:'**'+x+'**', outer()))
```

Output:

```
['**ATG**ATCG**ATG**C**TGA**', '**ATG**ATCG**ATG**C**TGA**', '**ATG**ATCG**ATG**C**TGA**', '**ATG**ATCG**ATG**C**TGA**', '**ATG**C**TGA**', '**ATG**C**TGA**', '**ATG**ATCG**ATG**C**TGA**', '**ATG**ATCG**ATG**C**TGA**', '**ATG**ATCG**ATG**C**TGA**', '**ATG**ATCG**ATG**C**TGA**', '**ATG**C**TGA**', '**ATG**C**TGA**']
```

Edit: regarding your recent data format change, you can create a function to find the overall groupings:

```
def combinations():
  groupings = {'G', 'ATG', 'ATCG', 'ATG', 'C', 'TGA', 'CGTA', 'TAG', 'GT', 'TAA', 'C'}
  seq = 'GATGATCGATGCTGACGTATAGGTTAAC'
  while seq:
    possibilities = [i for i in groupings if seq.startswith(i)]
    seq = seq[len(max(possibilities, key=len)):]
    yield max(possibilities, key=len)

seq = '**'.join(combinations())
results = list(map(lambda x:'**'+x+'**', outer()))
```

Comment: If i remove the stars from the seq, how would your code be? Thanks.